# How can i display button in two different colors on click the button

Tags: jquery

I need to display the button in white color for the first time and if user clicks on the button it should be turned to blue that means first buttonInactive 
style code class should be applied and if i click buttonActive I am enabling the prop to true in button click event but its not working

```
.buttonActive {
    background-color: #1E78AB;
    border: 1px solid #1E78AB;
    color: #fff;

}
.buttonInactive {
    background-color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #1E78AB;
    color: #1E78AB;

}
```

html code

```
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="buttonInactive">Test</button>
```

Jquery

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {

    });
```

Comment: Hint: check to see if `buttonActive` is present with jQuery's [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('buttonActive')){
       $(this).removeClass("buttonActive").addClass("buttonInactive");
       $('#idsToDisable').prop('disable', true);
     }else if($(this).hasClass('buttonInactive')){
       $(this).removeClass("buttonInactive").addClass("buttonActive");
       $('#idsToDisable').prop('disable', false);
     }
  });
});
```

Edited as per comment

Comment: but i need to hide textboxes and drop downs when the button is active and inactive suppose i have txt1,txt2,ddl1,ddl2 when button is active i should enable those 4 and when toggleclass becomes inactive i need to disable the those 4 fields how can i do this

Comment: @testuser you mustn't add additional information after a question has been answered - "I want to do A" "here's how you do A" "but that doesn't tell me how to do B-Z".  Put all the information in the question up front.  If there's additional information, *update* the question (making it clear it's an update).

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var myButton = $('#btn');
            myButton.click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('inActive')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('inActive').addClass('active');
                    $(this).css('color', 'blue');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inActive');
                    $(this).css('color', 'white');
                }
            });
```

```css
#btn{
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='inActive' id='btn'>Click here</button>
```

Comment: but i need to hide textboxes and drop downs when the button is active and inactive suppose i have txt1,txt2,ddl1,ddl2 when button is active i should enable those 4 and when toggleclass becomes inactive i need to disable the those 4 fields how can i do thi